# php: To get the name of a class by the method of another class

Tags: php, classname

I want to get the name of the class **Foo** by a method I set in the class **Foo**.
I can get the name of class Foo with **debug_backtrace()** below. Is there another way?

```
<?php

class Foo{

  public function index(){
      return (new Bar())->test();
  }  
}


class Bar{

    public function test(){
        $info = debug_backtrace();
        $info = array_column($info, 'class');
        $name = current(array_diff($info, array(__CLASS__)));
        return "'$name' class name";
    }
}


$foo = (new Foo())->index();
echo $foo; // 'Foo' class name
```

**-- UPDATE --**
My English is not good, I did not tell.
I want to do something like the following. Please write your answer accordingly.

```
index.php
<h1>Hello World</h1>


/view|
     |foo|index.php
     |    |menu.php
     |    |detail.php
     |    
     |user|login.php
          |register.php
```

I will get the file for the above directory path. The directory path and class name will be the same.

```
<?php
class Foo{

  public function index(){
      return (new Template())->view('index.php');
  }  
}


class User{

  public function index(){
      return (new Template())->view('login.php');
  }  
}


class Template{

    public function view($file_name){
        $info = debug_backtrace();
        $info = array_column($info, 'class');
        $name = current(array_diff($info, array(__CLASS__)));
        include("view/$name/$file_name");
    }
}


$foo = (new Foo())->index();

//Hello World
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [get_class](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) to get the object's class name.

```
class a {};
print get_class(new a());
# prints a
```

Or, you can use the [`__CLASS__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) constant within a class scope:

```
class Foo {
    public function getClassName() {
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}

print (new Foo())->getClassName();
# prints Foo
```

Comment: get_class, the name of the Bar class result. I tried it.

Comment: @jspcal But in this case,  `$this` is a `Bar` object, because of `(new Bar())->test()` in `Foo::index()`, not `Foo` as OP want.

Comment: I do not want to use parameters, so there is such a search.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you clearly ...

You can use the following constant.
`__CLASS__`

```
 1 <?php
 2 class Foo{
 3   public function index(){
 4        return __CLASS__;
 5   }
 6 }
 7
 8 echo (new Foo())->index()."\n";
```

---

## New Update : Another Way :

```
 1 <?php
 2 class A
 3 {
 4         public $name=__CLASS__;
 5         public function get_name()
 6         {
 7             return $this->name;
 8         }
 9 }
10 class B
11 {
12         public $name=__CLASS__;
13         public function get_name()
14         {
15            return $this->name;
16         }
17 }
18
19 echo (new A)->get_name();
20 echo "\n";
21 echo (new B)->get_name();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know these methods. Its purpose is to get without using parameters.